# Matrix representation of the derivative linear transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

I'm working on linear transformations and calculus. However, I can not find a solution to this problem.

Let
$$a = \left \{1 + x, 1 - x^{2}, 5  \right \} $$
be a basis for $P_2$, the space of degree $\leq 2$ polynomials.

Let $T : P_{2} \rightarrow P_{2}$ be the derivative linear transformation, that is,
$$T(p + qx + r x^{2}) = q + 2rx.$$

How can I find $[T]_{a}$, the matrix representation for $T$ in the basis $a$?

Finding the cartesian equation for $a$ and derivating it is the correct way ?

Comment: Why do you use two distinct symbols ($a$ and $P$) for the same thing? What is the Cartesian equation of a basis? What has this to do with [tag:linear-programming]?

Comment: I suppose that the transformation is: $T(p+qx+rx^2)=q+2rx$, Correct?

Comment: Yes ! $T(p+qx+rx2)=q+2rx$

Comment: What is the image of each of the basis vectors under $T$? Now write those images in terms of the basis vectors.

Comment: Do you mind developing a little bit more? It is not so clear to me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Each element (degree $\leq 2$ polynomial) in $P_2$ can be written as a linear combination of $1 + x$, $1 - x^2$, and $5$. Say e.g.
$$ 1 + x + x^2 = 1 (1 + x) - 1 (1 - x^2) + \frac{1}{5} (5). $$
So *in this basis*, we can think of $1 + x + x^2$ as the vector $(1, -1, 1/5)$.
The derivative of this particular polynomial is
$$ T(1 + x + x^2) = 1 + 2 x = 2 (1 + x) + 0(1 - x^2) - \frac{1}{5} (5), $$
or as a vector $(2, 0, -1/5)$.
So whatever $[T]_a$ is, it must be the case that $[T]_a (1, -1, 1/5) = (2, 0, -1/5)$.

---

In general, the way we find the matrix representations of linear transformations is playing this same game, only we need to know the image of the basis vectors themselves.

In this case, we have
$$ T(1 + x) = 1 = 0 (1 + x) + 0 (1 - x^2) + \frac{1}{5} (5), $$
so $[T]_a$ maps $(1, 0, 0)$ to $(0, 0, 1/5)$;
$$ T(1 - x^2) = -2 x = -2(1 + x) + 0(1 - x^2) + \frac{2}{5}(5), $$
so that $[T]_a$ maps $(0, 1, 0)$ to $(-2, 0, 2/5)$; and finally
$$ T(5) = 0 = 0 (1 + x) + 0(1 - x^2) + 0(5), $$
meaning that $[T]_a$ maps $(0, 0, 1)$ to $(0, 0, 0)$.

Putting this together we get the matrix representation
$$ [T]_a = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1/5 & 2/5 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
where the first column is the image of the first basis vector, the second column is the image of the second basis vector, and the third column (you guessed it) is the image of the third basis vector.

This idea, of looking at the image of the basis vectors in a prescribed basis, is the big idea! Since every input vector can be represented as linear combinations of the basis elements, and the operator $T$ is linear, this is all we need to know!

---

We can verify that indeed $[T]_a (1, -1, 1/5) = (2, 0, -1/5)$. More generally, we can verify that a generic degree $\leq 2$ polynomial works (and this is another way to approach the entire problem).
Consider
$$ p + q x + r x^2 = q (1 + x) - r(1 - x^2) + \frac{p - q + r}{5} (5). $$
In other words, the generic polynomial $p + q x + r x^2$, expressed in our basis, is $(q, -r, (p - q + r)/5)$.
The derivative of this is
$$ T(p + q x + r x^2) = q + 2 r x = 2 r( 1 + x) + 0(1 - x^2) + \frac{q - 2 r}{5} (5). $$
So we must have $[T]_a (q, -r, (p - q + r)/5) = (2r, 0, (q - 2 r)/5)$ (and indeed if you try it, we find that we do).

The way this gives another way to solve the problem is to imagine setting up a matrix equation
$$ \begin{pmatrix} ? & ? & ? \\ ? & ? & ? \\ ? & ? & ? \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} q \\ -r \\ \frac{p - q + r}{5} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2r \\ 0 \\ \frac{q - 2 r}{5} \end{pmatrix} $$
and tinkering to find out what the question marks have to be. E.g. for the first row, clearly the first entry has to be $0$, since the first row of the output has no $q$, and likewise the last entry of the first row has to be $0$, else there would be a $p$ in the first row of the output, which forces the second entry in the first row to be $-2$, and so on.

(This approach absolutely doesn't have to use that particular vector in the left-hand side, any arbitrary vector will work, like $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$, so long as you can figure out (by applying $T$) what the output vector has to be in the prescribed basis. I.e., computing something like $T(\alpha(1 + x) + \beta(1 - x^2) + \gamma(5)) = \dots$ and then expressing the result as a linear combination of the basis elements.)

---

Note finally that there's nothing special about this being a vector space of degree $\leq 2$ polynomials. The *exact* same ideas work for any finite dimensional vectors spaces with any bases and any linear transformations between them. In the case that you use a different basis on the "input" and "output" sides (maybe they're even different vector spaces), the same idea still applies, you just have to take care to use the right basis when converting the expressions.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is awsome !