# The derivative linear transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

I tried to do the question but I can't understand

Let $\alpha =(1,x,x^2)$

Let $\beta  = (1+x,1-x^2,5)$

Let $ TP{2}\rightarrow P{2}$ the derivative linear transformation, that is, $T(p+qx+rx^2) = q+2rx$

$[p(x)]{\beta } = \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}.$

how can I find $[T(p(x))]{\alpha }$

Comment: The idea is exactly like in my answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4316128/12880), only this time you need to use a different basis on either side of the transformation. The **exact** same idea applies though.

Comment: fixed ! It was a mistake

Comment: It is not clear what your question is asking now. You should explain what you're actually asking, and what you have tried.

Comment: If you're saying that a certain polynomial $p(x)$, expressed in basis $\beta$, has coordinates $(2, 1, 0)$, and you're asking for the coordinates in the basis $\alpha$ for $T(p(x))$, then, again, the idea is **exactly** the same as your last question. $[p(x)]_\beta = (2, 1, 0)$ tells you what the polynomial is, compute its derivative, and then express it in the new basis.

Comment: Do you mind developing? I will appreciate a lot !

Comment: I do mind, because you need to tell us what you've tried... And I also think you should read my response to your previous question very carefully and check that you understand it, because **all** the answers you need for this problem are in there.

Comment: It looks like someone else was working on the same problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316255/derived-linear-transformation